# WatchKit notification example

Tags: ios

Can someone just create a simple example without customizing too much about how to create a watchkit notification? Something very easy like if it's 10PM we can receive a notification like "It's time to sleep". Thanks in advance. It doesn't matter if the example is done using Swift or Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i was using this [tutorial](http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-actionable-notifications/) to learn WatchKit notification. Quite easy to understand and use.

Comment: Unfortunately only SWIFT (no objective c)